# How do I update a program installed from a manually-downloaded deb package?

Tags: updates, virtualbox, deb

I would like to update VirtualBox on my 32 bit Ubuntu 15.04 machine from 4.3.26 to 4.3.28, using a Debian package I manually downloaded from [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb). But simply double-clicking the package opens up the Software Centre which gives an error that installing it would break an existing package (the exact message was:

```
Breaks existing package 'virtualbox' conflict: virtualbox-4.3 ()
```

and it does not appear to have an option to ignore this and proceed with the installation anyway. Is there a command-line work-around this problem, perhaps?

Comment: "an error that installing it would break an existing package" Can you please edit your question and provide the actual message?

Comment: What's wrong with `purge` and reinstall?

Comment: I have a few virtualboxes already set up in VB, so wouldn't purging destroy the work I've already done with them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A better solution would be to add the oracle virtualbox ppa as described [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

(or even better to a new .list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d)
The Oracle public key for apt-secure can be downloaded [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc). You can add this key with

```
sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

or combine downloading and registering:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

The key fingerprint is

```
B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
<info@virtualbox.org>
```

To install VirtualBox, do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

If you want to stick to the cumbersome unlinuxy manual way, please try it using the command line, so that we can see which package would break.

```
dpkg -i package-file-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it using the command line not the `Software Center`.

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb
```

This would replace the old version without destroying your configurations and old machines.