# Can't get VirtualBox to work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, 16.04

I upgraded my HD and decided to start fresh with the most recent Ubuntu release. It works and I'm aware of the bug making it impossible to install third party software from within the software center. So far I had no problem installing those packages using the terminal with the dpkg command. But now I'm stuck... I want to install VirtualBox so that I can continue a pen testing course and we use Kali Linux in a virtual machine for our practicing and experiments. Are there any one else having this problem? Are there anyone else having a fix for it?

The problem is that VirtualBox gives an error about not being able to start the kernel driver. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I tried to reinstall the dkms package (I'm not sure if it is dkms - but at least something close to it). So, it boils down to being able to install virtual box but not being able to start a virtual machine.

Comment: If I remember correctly, virtualbox needs you to compile the driver first. It says "could not start the kernel driver" and tells you exactly which command to use. Am I right?

Comment: Use the ppa as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/633639/how-do-i-update-a-program-installed-from-a-manually-downloaded-deb-package/633646#633646

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use VirtualBox on *buntus, the best practice is to use Oracle's server and install it from there instead of using the one in the repos.

So, you should uninstall everything concerning VirtualBox that you've installed from the repos except for dkms.  dkms is the only thing you must install prior to installing VirtualBox.

You need to follow the instructions on putting the Oracle server on your system, here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

There is a 16.04 specific section that tells you exactly what to do with the keys.

After you install it successfully, you need to install the VirtualBox Extension pack which is available on this page: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue yesterday but i fixed by disable secure boot then run:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

Comment: no need to disable secure boot

Answer (score 0):

Install it through `synaptic` package manager. You will get those errors:

```
virtualbox-5.0:
 Depends: libqt4-opengl but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libsdl1.2debian but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libvpx1 (>=1.0.0) but it is not installable
 Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
```

You can install each of `libqt4-opengl`, `libsdl1.2debian`, `libsdl-ttf2.0-0` and `dkms` by searching and installing use synaptic itself, but you have to install `libvpx1` manually. To download `libvpx1` file please refer the following link:

[linuxandubuntu.com - SOLVED Virtualbox is not installing in Ubuntu 15.10 due to missing dependency](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/solved-virtualbox-is-not-installing-in-ubuntu-1510-due-to-missing-dependency-libvpx1)

then install it using the following commands:

```
cd /downloaded folder
sudo dpkg -i libvpx1_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
```

(Y)

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is not working because it is a 3rd party software and if UEFI secure boot is enable then ubuntu 16.04 will not install vboxdrv. So we have to disable UEFI secure boot.

1. go to synaptic package manager
2. search virtualbox-dkms
3. remove it (if you don't have synaptic, use the command `sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms`)
4. install it again from synaptic package manager
5. UEFI secure boot disable option will come
6. press yesy
7. enter password
8. retype password
9. reboot the machine
10. mok manger will appear
11. select 2nd option
12. write the password character as mentioned and enter..do it until finish
13. select yes

finish

Comment: Are you sure OP has Synaptic installed?

Comment: install virtualbox-dkms from synaptic package manager.

Comment: I mean, are you sure OP even *has* Synaptic Package Manager installed??

Comment: OP? What I did I explained clearly.

Comment: I mean OP might not even *have any trace of* Synaptic on their PC. OP did not specify if they have Synaptic or not, so I would not make such an assumption, as in your answer or Sameera's.

Comment: @Mashqur OP means original poster