# Installing Virtual Box

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualbox, 15.04, error-handling

I downloaded the virtual box deb from [here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

I had virtual box installed previously. So, I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-\*
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*
```

Now, I tried to install it from the deb, the software centre wont have the install button and says:

```
Breaks existing package 'virtualbox' that conflict: 'virtualbox'.
```

Also, the virtual box icon is still present on my system.

And when I open it: it says Runtime Error: File not found. (Since I Had deleted the previous Virtual Box folder).

I just want to install it. PLease help.

Comment: Someone already had this issue, and it has been resolved [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/633639/how-do-i-update-a-program-installed-from-a-manually-downloaded-deb-package) Basically, they say you should add the ppa repository for virtualbox
to your /etc/apt/sources.list I'm just posting this as an answer because i cant comment yet.

Comment: What happens if you download and install from the virtualbox website? They have a .deb there: [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)