# Can't install virtual box

Tags: command-line

When I go to the virtual box website I download the package when I countine to open it.It open up in the store I hit install it says  installing for a second then it goes back to install option and doesn't install please help.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/119531) solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry no the software center says installing for a second than goes back to install.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/633639/how-do-i-update-a-program-installed-from-a-manually-downloaded-deb-package/633646#633646https://askubuntu.com/questions/633639/how-do-i-update-a-program-installed-from-a-manually-downloaded-deb-package/633646#633646

Answer (score 2):

Install using command line.

Run the following command

```
$sudo dpkg -i <path to virtual box .deb package>
```

If you get any dependency error run the following command

```
$sudo apt-get install -f
```

**note** : No need to run the command `dpkg -i` for installing the package after running the `apt-get install -f` command, which does two jobs of fixing dependenies and also installing the package

I hope this answer would help.